# Chinese symbols on a Murakami painting?

Tags: translation, usage, meaning-in-context, characters

Recently at an art gallery, I was introduced to some works of [Takashi Murakami](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takashi_Murakami). On quite a few of his paintings were symbols which looked like Chinese, some sort of a seal perhaps. There was a painting I really liked and I took a snapshot

[image]

so we see three symbols and then what looks like a seal. This is just one corner of the huge painting. My question is, what are these symbols? What do they mean? Are they Chinese, Japanese, or Kanji? My guess is Chinese and hence the post here. Do they collectively have a meaning? Is there a meaning-in-context here perhaps because they are on a painting?

Comment: The three vertical characters look like 法橋隆 and the seal is 澗声. I guess they are related to the title of the painting and the name of the painter.

Comment: @user58955 So how do you translate these characters into English? What do they say?

Comment: As answered by Leo Liu below, 澗声 means the sound of mountain stream. I have no idea what 法橋隆 means holistically. It looks like a person's name.

Comment: `澗声` is just what @user58955 has explained (maybe it is the subject of the exhibition?). And in 法橋隆, [法橋](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/204466/m0u/%E6%B3%95%E6%A9%8B/) is a sort of title, and 隆 is the first name of the artist. You may have already noticed that, [Takashi Murakami](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takashi_Murakami), 村上隆, 村上(Murakami) is the surname, 隆(Takashi) is the first name.

Comment: “澗声”或是别号？看意思又像是闲章。

Comment: @LeoLiu after doing some search, I'm sure it is the subject of the works. See this [link](http://huanghs.pixnet.net/blog/post/31654758-%E6%88%91%E7%9A%842011%E7%BE%85%E8%8A%99%E5%A5%A7%E5%8F%B0%E5%8C%97%E6%98%A5%E6%8B%8D%E3%80%8C%E6%9D%91%E4%B8%8A%E9%9A%86%E3%80%8D%E4%B9%8B%E5%A4%A2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is “澗声”, which means the sound of the mountain stream.